# hql CASE statement excluding data from query

Tags: hibernate, hql, case-when

I have this query in hql:

```
SELECT d.code as row1, d.name as row2, d.contractor.name as row3, 
        case when e is null then 'no emission'
            else case when e.zone is null then 'no coverage' 
                else e.zone.name 
            end
        end
FROM Design d
    left join d.emissions e
WHERE (d.code =:codeParam or :codeParam = null)
    and (d.contractor =:contracParam or :contracParam = null)
```

I want this to list every Design even if it doesn't have an Emission or the Emission it has doesn't have a zone. If I only do:

```
case when e is null then 'no emission'
     else 'emission'
end
```

Every Design is listed correctly, but when I add the second **case-when** it only lists the Designs with zone.

What am I doing wrong? Please tell me if you need more information. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the structure:

```
case
   when ... then
   when ... then
   else ...
end
```

Read more in [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions).

Comment: That gives me the same result I'm having right now... what I need is an if within another if. Because I need to check if Emission is null and then if the emission's zone is null